# AWS CodeCommit commit message to Hipchat

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codecommit, hipchat

I want to send AWS CodeCommit commit message to a HipChat room. I already have a lambda function which gets triggered for a particular commit. What I need is to get commit detail messages from CodeCommit. Commit ID, commit message, branch name etc.

Answer (score 1):

Inside lambda you can require sdk then get parameters from lambda event.

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')

let codecommit = new AWS.CodeCommit();

var params = {
  commitId: 'STRING_VALUE', /* required */
  repositoryName: 'STRING_VALUE' /* required */
};
codecommit.getCommit(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

Depending on the info you get in lambda event parameters you can call one of those methods from sdk.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CodeCommit.html